# FIlebeat is not tracking the files in windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

We are using microservices, for the filebeat to work I have made a log file for each service. When testing the filebeat after downloading Zip file on windows it is working fine. The configuration on **filebeat.yml** is as follows.
[image: Filebeat.yml]

Now I want to move this setup to production through containerizing all the moving parts using docker-compose file.  Elastic search, Kibana and logstash are working perfectly fine. But when I use the same **filebeat.yml** file on the docker environment it is tracing the log files as they do in zip file download.

Approaches I used to test:

1. stopping the filebeat container and sending the logs from zip file(filebeat) to the 5044 port of docker container running on localhost, it is working fine in this condition.

docker-compose segment of filebeat is given below.
[image: docker-compose.yml]

Would love to have the solution for this problem on docker filebeat container.

Comment: I don't think either Compose or Filebeat accept PNG files as their configuration.  Can you [edit] the question and make sure to include your code and any relevant error messages as plain text, not image attachments?  This also doesn't obviously seem like a programming question, and questions about configuring log management might be better asked on another site like [sf] or [devops.se].

Comment: Thanks a lot.. will do that.